# ipsec package after decrypted can not be recieved by tproxy

Tags: linux, iptables, ipsec, strongswan

My centos6 machine ipaddress is 192.168.56.10 (eth0). I have installed strongswan and a tproxy like v2ray with iptables:

iptables:

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:SECGW_IN - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j SECGW_IN
-A SECGW_IN -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j RETURN
-A SECGW_IN -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
-A SECGW_IN -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A SECGW_IN -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
-A SECGW_IN -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
-A SECGW_IN -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
-A SECGW_IN -j LOG
-A SECGW_IN -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360
-A SECGW_IN -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port 44380 --tproxy-mark 1
-A SECGW_IN -p udp -j TPROXY --on-port 44380 --tproxy-mark 1
-A SECGW_IN -j DROP
COMMIT
```

route table:

```
[root@proxy logs]# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
200:    from all fwmark 0x1 lookup 200
201:    from all iif lo lookup 201
220:    from all lookup 220
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
[root@proxy logs]# ip route show table 200
local default dev lo  scope host
[root@proxy logs]#
```

v2ray as a tproxy server , configfile:

```
[root@proxy logs]# cat /etc/v2ray/config.json
{
  "log": {
    "loglevel": "debug",
    "access": "/tmp/access.log",
    "error": "/tmp/error.log"
  },
  "inbounds": [
    {
      "tag":"transparent",
      "port": 44380,
      "protocol": "dokodemo-door",
      "settings": {
        "network": "tcp,udp",
        "followRedirect": true
      },
      "sniffing": {
        "enabled": true,
        "destOverride": [
          "http",
          "tls"
        ]
      },
      "streamSettings": {
        "sockopt": {
          "tproxy": "tproxy"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outbounds": [{
    "protocol": "freedom",
    "settings": {}
  },{
    "protocol": "blackhole",
    "settings": {},
    "tag": "blocked"
  }],
  "routing": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "type": "field",
        "ip": ["geoip:private"],
        "outboundTag": "blocked"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

ipsec.conf

```
config setup
        cachecrls=yes
        uniqueids=never
        charondebug = "all"

conn %default
        ikelifetime=86400s
        keylife=86400s
        keyingtries=%forever
        keyexchange=ikev1
        authby=secret
        left=192.168.56.10
        leftid=192.168.56.10
        rightid=192.168.66.10
        right=192.168.66.10
        auto=start
        type=tunnel
        leftauth=secret
        rightauth=secret
        ike=aes256-md5-modp1024
        esp=aes256-md5


conn lan2public
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    rightsubnet=192.168.66.0/24
    type=tunnel
```

ipsec tunnel installed successed

```
[root@proxy logs]# strongswan status
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
  lan2public[1]: ESTABLISHED 64 minutes ago, 192.168.56.10[192.168.56.10]...192.168.66.10[192.168.66.10]
  lan2public{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: 33c16d9f_i 5c3b6118_o
  lan2public{1}:   0.0.0.0/0 === 192.168.66.0/24
```

when I use another machine (ip: 192.168.56.25,gw:192.168.56.10),do curl 8.8.8.8, on 192.168.56.10,package recieved by v2ray(some information in v2ray‘s log) ,this is correct。I can see log in /var/log/message by iptables:

```
May 26 09:06:45 proxy kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=08:00:27:0b:e3:62:08:00:27:10:ce:7b:08:00 SRC=192.168.56.25 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=18010 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59163 DPT=80 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0
```

when I use another machine (ip: 192.168.66.25,gw:192.168.66.10), this machine will use ipsec to 192.168.56.10, on 192.168.56.10, after ipsec decrypt, packetage write to ipsec0 interface, then go to prerouting, I can see it by iptables log:

```
May 26 10:51:52 proxy kernel: IN=ipsec0 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.66.25 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=24898 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51379 DPT=80 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

the diffrence is no MAC address. i can not see log of v2ray. may be v2ray sockets not return syn\ack？

who can explain this. I’d appreciate some help. what's wrong with me. thanks a lot.